# How does it follow from the Pascal's Triangle that binomial coefficient are integers

Tags: binomial-coefficients, integers, binomial-theorem

So I was reading this lemma which states:
Let $m,n$ be natural numbers such that $1 \leq m \leq n$. Then
\begin{equation*}
{n\choose m-1} + {n\choose m} = {n+1\choose m}.
\end{equation*}
It follows from this lemma using induction that the binomial coefficients are integers, rather than just rational numbers.

Using induction I could only prove that this equation is true for all natural numbers. How would I show that these coefficients are integers?

Comment: Note that $\binom{n}{0}=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ as well as $\binom{n}{k}=0$ for $k<0$.  Applying double induction then along with Pascal's identity and the well known property that the sum of two natural numbers is again a natural number will imply the result.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that, in this context, $\binom nm$ is defined as$$\binom nm=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}.$$With this definition, it is clear that $\binom nm\in\mathbb Q$, but it is not clear that it is an integer.

However, it *is* clear that $\binom n0=\binom nn=1$, which is an integer. And, since$$\binom n{m-1}+\binom nm=\binom{n+1}m,$$it follows (by induction on $n$), that each $\binom nm$ is an integer.